# why is the iframe contents empty?

Tags: php, javascript, iframe

I'm trying to understand this bit of code:

in display.php:

```
<html>
...
<body>
  <table>
     <tr>
       <td>
         User info: <iframe id="SpControlFrame1" name="SpControlFrame1" src="javascript:'';"path_src="index.php?cmd=YYY" ></iframe>
        </td>
     </tr>
   </table>
 </body>
 </html>
```

in  another file, I have a switch statement:

main.php

```
switch ("cmd") {
 case ZZZ:
   include("foo.php");
   break;
 case YYY:
   include("blah.php")
   break;
}
```

blah.php:

```
<?php
 //some functions for processing
?>
<html>
 <head>
  ...
 </head>
 <body>
   <input type="text" size="12" name="username">
   <input type="button" value="submit">
  </body>
</html>
```

1) So, can some explain what is happening here? The iframe is embedded in the page and doesn't cause a reload or anything like that.

2) I'm trying to duplicate this functionality on another page but the iframe is always empty (I've verified this using the IE developer Toolbar)

Comment: We are going to need a bit more code so we can help.

Comment: Some code formatting would also be nice.

Comment: It would also be nice if the Question was in the form of a Question and less generic

Comment: Still missing how you actually load an page into the iframe. Where is the JavaScript magic that uses the path_src?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the code in question, I couldn't really say what's happening.  Your example presumes that the code in question is server-side, and when a particular variable/condition is met, then the iframe is created or populated by blah.php.

You would have to ensure that the same code is called when creating this other iframe.  Perhaps you could expand on the code in question?  Source for the original, and source for the new (not the iframe, but the containing document).

Answer (score 0):

How does this work for you?

```
User info: <iframe id="SpControlFrame1" name="SpControlFrame1" src="index.php?cmd=YYY" ></iframe>
```